# weird behavior of numpy.histogram / random numbers in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, random, statistics

I stumbled upon some peculiar behavior of random numbers in Python , specifically I use the module numpy.random.

Consider the following expression:

```
n = 50
N = 1000
np.histogram(np.sum(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(n, N)), axis=0), bins=n+1)[0]
```

In the limit of large `N` I would expect a binomial distribution (for the interested reader, this simulates the [Ehrenfest model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_model)) and for large `n` a normal distribution. A typical output however, looks like this:

> array([
>   1,   0,   0,   1,   0,   2,   0,   1,   0,  15,   0,
>   12,  0,  18,   0,  39,   0,  64,   0,  62,   0, 109,
>   0,  97,   0, 107,   0, 114,   0, 102,   0,  92,   0,
>   55,   0,  46,   0,  35,   0, 10,   0,   9,   0,   4,
>   0,   0,   0,   3,   0,   1,   1
>   ])

With the statement from above, I can't explain the occurrence of the zeros in the histogram - am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `histogram` wrong. The bins aren't where you think they are. They don't go from 0 to 50; they go from the minimum input value to the maximum input value. The 0s represent bins that lie entirely between two integers.

Try it with `numpy.bincount`:

```
In [31]: n = 50

In [32]: N = 5000

In [33]: np.bincount(np.sum(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(n, N)), axis=0))
Out[33]: 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   7,  13,  22,  46,  75, 126, 220, 305, 367, 461, 550, 578,
       517, 471, 438, 314, 189, 146,  76,  50,  17,   9,   2,   1])
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness: the desired behavior is achieved when passing  `minlength=n+1` to `np.bincount` to achieve a list over the entire span.